# "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)"

Tags: java, arrays

The exercise is about using arrays to get student grades and names, then calculating avarage score and lastly show the names for the above avarage students only. Altough not ideal the algorithm seems right (as it works just fine in NetBeens and repl.it IDEs), but I'm getting this [error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84KzL.png) in my school's website IDE (idk which exactly). I assume somethings is not ideal with the way I coded, tho it isn't shown in some IDEs.

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner e = new Scanner (System.in);
    int n= e.nextInt();
    double media = 0;
    double not [] = new double [n];
    String nom [] = new String [n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
      not[i]= e.nextDouble();
      nom [i]= e.next();
      media = media + not[i];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
      if (not[i]>=media/n){
      System.out.println(nom[i]);
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

InputMismatchException means that your entered something other than expected by the scanner , I advice you to use debugger to easely find the line throwing the exception ,and why not control the input and convert it if needed